# Correct dateformat for String

Tags: java, date

I'm receiving an exception when parsing the following date:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
    Date parsedDate=null;
    try {
        parsedDate=sdf.parse("Thu Jan 26 15:05:48 COT 2012");
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Is the pattern incorrect? What would be the correct form to parse the date string?+

Comment: Looks like you have done little or no research at all [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: @ringbearer I did in fact... that's why I came up with that pattern... however I didn't knew about the Locale in the SimpleDateFormat. +1 to andresoviedo for actually answering the question instead of blaming...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default SimpleDateFormat constructor doesn't support all Locales.

You would have to specify the Locale:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
Date parsedDate = null;
try {
    parsedDate = sdf.parse("Thu Jan 26 15:05:48 COT 2012");
    System.out.println(parsedDate);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I solved the same problem by specifying the Locale only. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try using only one `z`:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you ever tried a single 'z' instead of a triple 'z' ?

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
```

Should become

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried that... however I'm still getting: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu Jan 26 15:05:48 COT 2012"

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you [need to use `CO` instead of `COT`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Colombia) for the timezone?